# Jailkit not allowing SSH connections

Tags: ssh, debian, chroot

I'm trying to set up jailkit on one of my servers which is running Debian 5. I created a new ssh user (bob) and a chroot directory for him (/var/www/bob). I gave the chroot the extshellplusnet and limitedshell options with the following commands:

```
jk_init -c /etc/jailkit/jk_init.ini -j /var/www/bob/ extshellplusnet
jk_init -c /etc/jailkit/jk_init.ini -j /var/www/bob/ limitedshell
```

And then I jailed him:

```
jk_jailuser -m -j /var/www/bob bob
```

When I try to ssh in as bob, it connects, I get the banner, and then it disconnects. My auth.log looks like this:

```
Aug 25 05:04:36 server sshd[29885]: Accepted password for bob from 123.45.6.7 port 50624 ssh2
Aug 25 05:04:36 server sshd[29885]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user bob by (uid=0)
Aug 25 05:04:36 server jk_chrootsh[29942]: now entering jail /var/www/bob for user bob (1001) with arguments 
Aug 25 05:04:36 server sshd[29885]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user bob
```

My non-jailed users work just fine, and I don't seem to be getting any permission errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly turn you SSH logs to DEBUG3 by replacing in the sshd_config file :
`LogLevel INFO`
by
`LogLevel DEBUG3`

You will see more information why SSH did close the connection.

Then Ensure you have all the shell need to run in chrooted environment :

- The user home is there with the right permissions
- All shell need to be lauched in the chroot directory (shell executable and all librairies)
- All the components such as passwd, group, hosts, nsswitch.conf, resolv.conf, shadow are in the /var/www/bob/etc
- The `null` pseudo device is the /var/www/bob/dev directory. You can create it typing :
  `mknod /var/www/bob/dev/null c 1 3`
- Then if it still does not work, I recommand you to debug your chroot environment with the `strace` command.

`strace chroot /var/www/bob/ /bin/bash`

Comment: Everything looked good, I even straced a good user and the jailed user and those matched up (other than memory mapping, but that's expected). I ended up copying /bin/bash to the chroot and changing the jailed user to use /bin/bash instead of /usr/sbin/jk_lsh  as the shell, and it worked. /usr/sbin/jk_lsh exists in the chroot, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: You also can strace the /usr/sbin/jk shell to see why it doesn't work.
strace is your best friend when chrooting environments.